# Android sum all values from SQLite database to textview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

What I want to do is to get all values from a column in a database table, add the values up and show the sum of these values in a TextView. What I have tried so far is:

```
public int addAllValues(){

  int total = 0;

  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + (K_SALARY) + ") FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
  if(c.moveToFirst()){
    total = c.getInt(0);
  }
  return total;
}
```

And in main:

```
int sum = myDb.addAllValues();
DaySalary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDaySalary);
DaySalary.setText(sum);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. This is the error I get:

```
      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ad.salarycount, PID: 4236
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x15
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
                  at com.example.ad.salarycount.MySalary.addIhop(MySalary.java:71)
                  at com.example.ad.salarycount.MySalary.access$100(MySalary.java:22)
                  at com.example.ad.salarycount.MySalary$1.onClick(MySalary.java:52)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert integer to String:

```
 DaySalary.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Or

```
 DaySalary.setText(sum+"");
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! But now the values that i have in the database dont show up on the textview. Instead i get 0, which i have set total to.

Comment: Then check addition method.

Comment: Nevermind this solved my problem. Thank you very much for responding!